# Could a naturalised British citizen lose his/her citizenship after moving abroad?

Tags: united-kingdom, citizenship

Basically this question is in relation to UK citizenship requirement of having the intent of continuing to live in the UK. At the moment, I have that intent. However, you never know where life might take you.

I am currently applying for British citizenship. Lets say for whatever reason a job opportunity arose for me outside the UK ‘’After’’ I was granted British ciizenship. Lets say the UAE or something. If I moved there, would I lose my British ciizenship? Even if I intend to return to the UK in the end?

Answer (score 4):

No. Living elsewhere is not grounds for deprivation of citizenship.

The Secretary of State has the power to deprive an individual of their British citizenship on two occasions:

If the Secretary of State is satisfied that deprivation is “conducive to the public good” (section 40(2)); or

If the Secretary of State is satisfied that the registration or naturalisation (from which the citizenship resulted) was obtained by means of:

- Fraud,
- False representation, or
- Concealment of a material fact.

Source: https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/nationality-and-borders-bill-deprivation-of-citizenship-factsheet/nationality-and-borders-bill-deprivation-of-citizenship-factsheet

Nationality policy guidance: https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/631643/deprivation-nullity-Chapter-55.pdf